# Open a new window displaying the google search results

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

When user selects a text, my extension automatically searches on google the selected text and the search results are displayed on a new popup window.

```
var searchWindow = ww.openWindow(null, "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI(annotateSelectText)+"",
                    "searchWindow", "menubar=0,status=0,width=750,height=750", null);
```

I need few suggestions and sample code if possible on how to go about achieving what I need. I want to add check boxes in the beginning of each search results.
So the user can check the search results that are relevant to them and save that url and text snippet in SQLite. I am bit confused with regard to adding checkboxes in the google search result window.

Any suggestions?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying Google's search result page, consider using their [ajax search api](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/). It will give you the url, title, text snapshot etc in the response and you can display it the way you want.

I once made a little Firefox extension [LinkIt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9003) using that API - may be you wanna download it and examine the code :)

Comment: Thanks Amar,
The LinkIt extension was of great help. And i learnt something new-> AJAX search api.
cheers